# Stop client from having access to collection (MeteorJS)

Tags: meteor, collections

My application is a calorie counter and the user enters a bunch of foods he ate w/the calories and my application counts it up. I've removed both autopublish and insecure and after following a tutorial, I learned how to publish and subscribe to a collection.

I have a collection :

```
Meals = new Mongo.Collection("meals-info");
```

Client Side :

```
Meteor.subscribe('meals-info');
```

Server Side :

```
Meteor.publish('meal-info', function() {
 return Meals.find();
});
```

I've searched on the web but all the ones I've found have something to do w/having a user account package. My application doesn't require any user account information which is why I'm a little confused on how to approach this or whether I'm even approaching this the correct way.

Comment: "The user enters a bunch of foods he ate" - what is the _id of this user? How do you tell one apart from another?

Comment: @Michel Floyd That's what I was thinking too. Essentially, the way I've been thinking about it, there is no way to tell one apart from another. But it makes sense though. What would you advise? I just feel like the whole account system approach is kind of unnecessary. Is there any other way to possibly differentiate the users? And I'm storing this information in a collection. There is a random _id given but its not consistent

Comment: If you could depend on them always coming in from the same browser you could just use a cookie or persistent session variable to identify the user. Really not reliable though. Or you can use a 3rd party authentication system to give you user identifiers, i.e. facebook login.

Comment: But you would recommend some sort of account login approach? I know Meteor has ways to use FB login as well. Arg..I wanted to get away from the whole account approach but reliability is def. important.

Comment: Pick the auth system that your users will be most comfortable with, but you can't really avoid it and get good results.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Figured it out. Um do you want to possibly write your comments as a possible answer? That way I can give you credit.